# How do I fix error: "invalid use of non static data member for a pointer object"?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class BinaryTree {
    public:
        BinaryNode* root;
        
        bool search(int val, BinaryNode* zero = root){ // Error
            ...
       }
};
```

I have tried to add a `static` access specifier to `root` but it throws  `error: undefined reference to BinaryTree::root'`

Comment: As for `bool search(int val, BinaryNode* zero = root)`, the static member will not help here. Use `nullptr` instead of `root` and a condition in the inside.

Comment: Any chance you meant this:

Comment: bool search(int val, BinaryNode* zero = nullptr){
if (zero==nullptr)
zero = root;

Comment: Yes, you have understood me correctly.